# Django ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table

Tags: django, postgresql, psql

There are many similar questions on Stackoverflow, but none of the answers has helped me.

So, when running migrations, Django throws this error:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "catalogues_movieslist"

I have this **BlackWhiteCartoon** model I am trying to create with the migration:

```
class BlackWhiteCartoon(BaseMovie, BaseList):
    authors = JSONField(default=list, blank=True, null=True)
    publisher = CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    year = PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This model inherits from the **BaseList** model that has only one field, a foreign key:

```
class BaseList(Model):
    belongs_to_movies_list = ForeignKey(MoviesList, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

The referenced **MoviesList** model is the following:

```
class MoviesList(Model):
    creation_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    uid = UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

Also, the **BaseMovie** model is the following:

```
class BaseMovie(BaseObject):
    language = CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    note = CharField(max_length=700, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

And the **BaseObject** model:

```
class BaseObject(Model):
    id = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    uid = UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, db_index=True)
    date_added = DateTimeField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

So, what I have tried:

1. Migrating everything together: this throws the above error.
2. Migrating BlackWhiteCartoon without inheriting BaseList first. This migration applies, but as soon as I add BaseList, it crashes with the same error.
3. Adding *unique=True* to the **id** field of MoviesList (both together with all other migrations and before adding BaseList to BlackWhiteCartoon). It throws the same error.
4. Adding *to_field='id'* together with 'unique=True'. The same error.
5. I have manually cleared the latest migrations from django_migrations in PSQL and removed the BlackWhiteCartoon table (to make sure that nothing prevents from migrating). To no avail either.
6. I have checked whether there are duplicated id's in the MoviesList table in the database. All id's are unique.
7. I have checked whether there are null foreign keys referencing to MoviesList in the database. There are none.

Also note that I have many models acting in absolutely the same way as BlackWhiteCartoon: Cartoon, Adventure, Action, etc. They are all functioning normally, yet they had been added several months ago.

Any ideas what I can do more?

Comment: Are all of these base classes/models "abstract"? Do they have `abstract = True` in their `Meta` classes?

Comment: @IainShelvington Yes, except for BlackWhiteCartoon. I have updated the descriptions.

Comment: @Edmond If MoviesList is abstract how do you expect to have a ForeignKey to it?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat It is not abstract. I made en error editing the post. Corrected the descriptions. The rest is correct.

Comment: Hi ,have you solved this issue,I met the similar issue,can you help me:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69922311/django-postgres-there-is-no-unique-constraint-matching-given-keys-for-reference